# Password check program

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a password checking program for a class. The program has specific password requirements just as all password checkers do. I have all he error checks on there and they all work but if the program encounters a field that doesn't meet the requirements in the nested if-else statements, it ignores every if and else after that and doesn't print the errors it encounters.

```
minlength = (8)
valid = False
pw = str(input("Insert new password."))
num = sum(1 for c in pw if c.isnumeric())
alpha = sum(1 for c in pw if c.isalpha())
if len(pw) >= minlength:
    valid = True
    print(valid)
    if pw.isalnum():
        valid = True
        print(valid)
        if num >= 1:
            valid = True
            print(valid)
            if alpha >= 1:
                valid = True
                print(valid)
                if valid == True:
                    print("Your new password is valid.")
                else:
                    print("Your new password is not valid.")
            else: 
                valid = False
                print(valid)
                print("Error, password must contain at least one letter.")
        else:
            valid= False
            print(valid)
            print("Error, password must contain at least one number.")          
    else: 
        valid = False
        print(valid)
        print("Error, password is not alphanumeric.")
else:
    valid = False
    print(valid)
    print("Error, password is less than",minlength,"characters.")
```

Is there a way so it prints out every error statement that it encounters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a list of errors: `errors = list()`.

Don't nest the `if` blocks.

Every time you encounter an error add it to the errors list: `errors.append(error)`.

At the very end check if `len(errors) == 0`. That means the password is ok. Otherwise print the errors:

```
for err in errors: 
  print err
```

Example:

```
errors = list()
if len(pw) < minlength:
  errors.append('Not enough characters')
if alpha < 1:
  errors.append('At least a number is required')
if not errors:
  print 'Password is valid'
else:
  print 'Password is not valid'
  for err in errors:
    print err
```

Comment: All of that works but now I'm trying to make a check to see if the characters are all alphanumeric. The code I tried is 
`if pw != pw.isalnum():  
    errors.append("Must be alphanumeric")`

I think i have the right syntax but no matter what, it always says that the password isn't alphanumeric.

Comment: @Rogue_Monkeys `isalnum` return `True` if the password is alphanumeric and `False` otherwise. The check should be `if pw.isalnum():`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the errors, you could append them to a list. And so, at the end of the checking flow, you will have an empty list (if everything went well), or have all the errors that the check flow encountered